# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Update

Tags: updates

I check my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system for available updates on a regular base. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is not provided to download.

Comment: I've checked the settings that you recommended. Everything is ok, but no update version shown.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Software & Updates` and check this setting... then click the Close button, and approve reloading the software database, if it asks. If you then use Software Updater, it'll show when 18.04.1 LTS is available.

[image]

Comment: There again, as others have written, you might best now wait for the first point release of 18.04.1 due sometime in the next coming months.

Comment: @Graham And why would that be?

Comment: In fact, I modify my response based on this article which will guide me on whether or not to upgrade just yet - https://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-18-04-1-slated-for-release-on-july-26-ubuntu-16-04-5-could-land-august-2-521348.shtml

Comment: @Graham that article is moot. From the article... as expected... "**don't expect Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to incorporate any major changes or new features** because it's only a bugfix release shipping with updated components. Most probably, **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS will include all the updates that have been released through the main software repositories until July 26, 2018**". Go ahead and upgrade now.

Comment: OP is asking about updating to LTS release, not just any release.

Comment: @wvxvw why did you down vote my answer? If the setting is not set correctly, the user may not receive updates about new versions.

Comment: OP was very specific about updating to *LTS* release.  What you suggest will not do that.  It will allow updating to any release.

Comment: @wvxvw yes, but the 18.04.1 LTS version WILL show up with my settings... just not right away.

Comment: Loo, I don't know... question answering is, in general, a difficult problem. Beside being correct, one also needs to be on-topic, and that means that answers to "how much is 5 times 5" could be "between 1 and 197" or "square root of 625", but neither will be seen as a good answer. I don't think therefore that you gave a good answer. On the other hand, I feel badly downvoting someone who put an effort towards answering, so I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @wvxvw were you going to remove your down vote? I don't see the change.

Comment: Thank retards from SE. I now cannot withdraw my vote, unless you edit the question.

Comment: @wvxvw aren't you just able to click the up arrow to withdraw your vote?

Comment: Nope. But you can make any meaningless edit and I'll cancel my vote. You can restore the changes after I cancel. I don't think the system is smart enough to figure something like that out. After all, no smart person participated in its conception.

Comment: Dopwnvote removed.